# undefined is not an object '_this3.props.navigation()' error in react native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

running my react app gives error in navigationOptions() but it is working fine in render() function

App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View } from 'react-native';
import AppNavigator from './routs.js'


class App extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <AppNavigator />
      )
   }
}
export default App
```

routs.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import Home from './home.js'
import Phone from './phone.js'
import PhoneScreen from './phoneScreen.js'
import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';


const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({

  home: {screen: Home},
  add: {screen: Phone},
  userScreen: {screen: PhoneScreen},

});

const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

export default AppNavigator;
```

home.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import { TouchableOpacity, Text, View, TouchableHighlight, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';


class Home extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) { 
  super(props); 
 }

 static navigationOptions = {
  headerTitle: 'Contacts',
  headerRight: (
   <Button
   onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('add')}
   title="create new contact"
   color="#000000"
   size="20"
   />
   ),
      };
}
export default Home;
```

"undefind is not an object(evaluating '_this3.props.navigation')"

please give solution

Answer (score 1):

From the [React Navigation Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/header-buttons.html):

> The binding of this in navigationOptions is not the HomeScreen
>   instance, so you can't call setState or any instance methods on it.
>   This is pretty important because it's extremely common to want the
>   buttons in your header to interact with the screen that the header
>   belongs to.

So, as you can see, `this` is not what you think it is in this case. Here's more from the docs detailing a working example:

```
 class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      headerTitle: <LogoTitle />,
      headerRight: (
        <Button
          onPress={navigation.getParam('increaseCount')}
          title="+1"
          color="#fff"
        />
      ),
    };
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({ increaseCount: this._increaseCount });
  }

  state = {
    count: 0,
  };

  _increaseCount = () => {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  };

  /* later in the render function we display the count */
}
```

As you can see, changing `navigationOptions` from an object into a function allows you to grab the `navigation` reference. From there you can successfully `navigate`.